# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in specific folder

Tags: linux, jsp, tomcat

A few months ago, I was making changes to this web application for a client.  It's a JSP web application with tomcat as the web server.  I've made the changes, tested it (of course), and left the application to the client's hands.  They have come back to me and mentioned that a specific area of the website is not working.  I go in and check the area, indeed it wasn't working but it was working a few months ago when I made the changes.

The issue encountering a very unusual.  Every page in the directory in question (/tomcat/webapps/website/english/login) throws a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.

To troubleshoot the issue, I've tried creating a blank JSP with "hello world" and no coding and still throws a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.  I create the same JSP page outside of this directory and it is fine

Steps taken to replicate this issue:

1. I enter into the directory in question (tomcat/webapps/website/english/login)
2. Create a JSP page called test.jsp that literally has "hello world" only (no coding)
3. On the browser, I navigate to test.jsp.  It throws a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
4. I enter into the directory one up from login (tomcat/webapps/website/english)
5. Create a JSP page called test2.jsp that literally has "hello world" only (no coding)
6. On the browser, I navigate to the test2.jsp page.  It works

I've done other test but could not find the issue.  See below for some methods performed

- Moved the web application into a different directory (tomcat/webapps/website2).  Everything, including the /english/login directory, works
- Deleted the web application directory and recreated the directory path, still giving me the exception
- Checked permissions.  The directory in question has the same permissions as everything else in the web application (including the files)

With the results from the tests, I believe the issue is the directory itself (/tomcat/webapps/english/login).  Everytime I move the directory, everything works.

Mind you that I was making changes to the web application using a text editor (notepad++) not on eclipse, building the application using TeamCity (which compiled fine), the server runs under linux and I have no access to the build script but I believe ANT is used as the builder

So my question is, what is causing this issue? To have all the files in a specific directory to look for a class?

Any clues/help is much appreciated.  I've been working on this problem for a few days.  It's mind boggling

Cheers!

Comment: Do you already have a servlet mapped to that url? i.e. `english/login`

Comment: How do you find out if a servlet is already mapped to the url?

Answer (score 0):

I would check the class path being used with PS -ef and look for the process. The error logs should point to a specific class. Those two clues can help determine if is config or war issue.

A possibility that I have seen is that in a tomcat config file, the paths allowed are explicitly defined. Also, a config file could map a specific path to a java class.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my own problem.  The issue originates in Tomcat.  The web server converts the JSP file into a .java file then compiles it.  For some odd reason, Tomcat was not doing this for all my files in a specific folder.

Solution is to go into Tomcat's work folder, drill down until you see your webapp's name and delete the folder.  This will force Tomcat to rebuild all the visited pages.

A safer way (which didn't work for me.  Did not delete the webapp in the work folder) is to log into Tomcat and undeploy the webapp all together.  This should delete the webapp folder in the work folder of tomcat.

Hope this helps for those experiencing similar issues